# Can we have hidden heading elements in a Wordpress page that are still displayed in a summary block?

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg

Please look at this [webpage](https://www.trucklesoft.co.uk/cut-tools-software-suite/) (WordPress).

Towards the top is a summary block which is built from the heading elements on the page.

Towards the bottom are three downloads. Is it possible to have the three headings "Cut-Tools for ..." and have them invisible? My conundrum is that I need those heading elements so that they show as links in the summary but I don't want anything visible.

Am I asking too much of the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS to selectively hide the element without removing them from the page. From the WordPress Admin, nagivate to `Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS` and add a new CSS class:

```
.hide{
    display:none;
}
```

[image: Customize > Additional CSS]

Remember to click "Publish" so the new CSS is saved.

Next, open the Page/Post Editor and select the block of the element you want to "hide" and add the new CSS class and save:

[image: Additional CSS Class]

The CSS in this case only applies to the front end so the block/content will still be visible in the Editor so you can edit it, but hidden on the front end. This is just a general example and you could make the css more specific to hide elements that are/are not children of other elements etc.